# How to connect to database in Vagrant box using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vagrant

I'm using Laravel and Vagrant.

I have a database set up in vagrant, what settings do I need to enter in the Laravel database config file to connect to it?

I've tried localhost but no luck. Could someone point me in the right direction.

I know what the username and password is, it's just connection to it that's the problem.

Comment: Really broad question, because this would completely depend on how you have vagrant setup, and how you're using the virtual machine. I'll take a shot in the dark and say try `0.0.0.0` though.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work.Do you know of any tutorials on this?

Comment: So many questions.... Is MySQL on the same vagrant box? Is MySQL *installed* in your vagrant VM? Can you connect to MySQL "manually" in cli? Have you set any network settings from the defaults in your Vagrant config? We need more info to work with :D

Comment: Which Vagrant box do you installed? Which database?

Comment: It's mysql in my vagrant vm. I can connect to it via ssh and navicat but i'm having trouble with what ip to use in the laraval database settings. I connect to it via ssh in navicat. Not sure how to do this is laravel database settings.

Comment: What error do you get in Laravel? I'm wondering If its actually a connection issue. How are your environments setup?

Comment: @user1013512 which host do you use when connecting via SSH?

Answer (score 1):

To know the address which MySQL is bound to do the following:

1. SSH into you Vagrant box.
2. Type: `cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep bind-address`, press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it will show the address to use.
3. Use that host in `app/config/database.php`.

---

Note: If you hasn't created a user in MySQL for remote access you will need to do that before. From the terminal you can do (only in dev environment):

```
mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

Then you will have a `root` user with no password.